# Allow only one item to be selected in four Checkboxlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Please help me to select one item in four checkboxlist.
Right now, I got 4 selected item in four checkboxlist using this reference
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Mutually-Exclusive-CheckBoxList-Control-in-ASP.Net.aspx

It's a big change if I used radiobutton or combine the 4 checkboxlist to 1.
Thanks in advance.

I'm using asp.net, vb.net and javascript
This is my code:

Checkboxlist #1

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="wklyYr1Q1S1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="horizontal"
    style="border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC; margin-top:4px;">
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W1" Value="W1" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W2" Value="W2" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W3" Value="W3" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W4" Value="W4" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W5" Value="W5" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W6" Value="W6" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W7" Value="W7" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W8" Value="W8" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W9" Value="W9" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W10" Value="W10" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W11" Value="W11" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W12" Value="W12" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W13" Value="W13" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Checkboxlist #2

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="wklyYr1Q2S1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="horizontal"
    Style="margin-left: 60px; border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: #DCDCDC; border-bottom-style: solid;">
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W14" Value="W14" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W15" Value="W15" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W16" Value="W16" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W17" Value="W17" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W18" Value="W18" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W19" Value="W19" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W20" Value="W20" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W21" Value="W21" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W22" Value="W22" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W23" Value="W23" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W24" Value="W24" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W25" Value="W25" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W26" Value="W26" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Checkboxlist #3

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="wklyYr1Q3S1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="horizontal"
    Style="margin-left: 60px; border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: #DCDCDC; border-bottom-style: solid;">
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W27" Value="W27" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W28" Value="W28" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W29" Value="W29" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W30" Value="W30" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W31" Value="W31" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W32" Value="W32" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W33" Value="W33" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W34" Value="W34" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W35" Value="W35" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W36" Value="W36" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W37" Value="W37" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W38" Value="W38" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W39" Value="W39" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Checkboxlist #4

```
<asp:CheckBoxList  ID="wklyYr1Q4S1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="horizontal"
    Style="margin-left: 60px; border-bottom: 1px; border-bottom-color: #DCDCDC; border-bottom-style: solid;">
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W40" Value="W40" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W41" Value="41" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W42" Value="42" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W43" Value="W43" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W44" Value="W44" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W45" Value="W45" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W46" Value="W46" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W47" Value="W47" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" style="display: none"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W48" Value="W48" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W49" Value="W49" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W50" Value="W50" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W51" Value="W51" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text=":W52" Value="W52" onclick="MutExChkList(this);"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function MutExChkList(chk)
    {
        var chkList = chk.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        var chks = chkList.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=0;i<chks.length;i++){
            if(chks[i] != chk && chk.checked){
                chks[i].checked = false; }
            }
    }
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To wklyYr1Q1S1.Items.Count - 1
    wklyYr1Q1S1.Items(i).Attributes.Add("onclick", "MutExChkList(this)")
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To wklyYr1Q2S1.Items.Count - 1
    wklyYr1Q2S1.Items(i).Attributes.Add("onclick", "MutExChkList(this)")
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To wklyYr1Q3S1.Items.Count - 1
    wklyYr1Q3S1.Items(i).Attributes.Add("onclick", "MutExChkList(this)")
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To wklyYr1Q4S1.Items.Count - 1
    wklyYr1Q4S1.Items(i).Attributes.Add("onclick", "MutExChkList(this)")
Next
```

Comment: So you want only one item checked at any given time in any of the checkboxlist if I understand you correctly?

Comment: In four checkboxlist, I want to select only one.

Comment: Example I tick the one checkbox in **Checkboxlist #1**, when I tick one checkbox in **Checkboxlist #2**, the checkbox that I tick in **Checkboxlist #1** get uncheck.

Comment: Did I miss something? if you can only choose one why not make it a drop list. You could even use selectize.js though it wouldn't be hard to add vanilla

Comment: @JustDave, currently my system is designed by the used of Checkboxlist. As I mention in my question above, there's a big changes in my system if I used radiobuttons, dropdownlist and etc. That's why I stick with CheckboxList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's occurring is that you're JavaScript isn't going 'up' the DOM enough. The ASP.Net CheckboxList renders inside of a table. So the ".parent.parent.parent" call in your MutExChkList function provides a reference to the TABLE element which it then looks in for checkboxes. You would need an unknown number of .parent calls to gather the appropriate container aspects for scanning multiple CheckboxLists for checkboxes.

Alternatively, you can just hunt for all checkboxes in the DOCUMENT and work with all of them. Modifying your JS to do something like this, may work for what you need.

```
function MutExChkList(chk) {
    var cbs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
    for(var i=0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
         if (cbs[i].id <> chk.id) { 
           cbs[i].checked = false;
         }
    }
}
```

All of that said, for what you're trying to do, a single RadioButtonList would work better. Or even multiple RadioButtonLists which all have the same GROUPNAME should accomplish what you're attempting.  Additionally, using a Repeater would allow you greater control over the resulting markup than either the RadioButtonList OR the CheckboxList. Greater control over markup means you don't need to have it inside a table.

### **Edit**

For older browsers, try this:

```
function MutExChkList(chk) {
   var cbs= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   for(var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
      if(cbs[i].type == "checkbox") {
         if (cbs[i].id <> chk.id) {
            cbs[i].checked = false;
         } 
      }     
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Stephen thanks for your response I modified may js but I got a JavaScript runtime error: Object doen't support property or method 'querySelectorAll', Is it because I'm using IE 11?

Comment: @GlydelGorospe -- That's probable. I'm not certain which version received support for querySelectorAll. I've updated the question with older JS that should work.

Comment: we are so close in solving this haha but the problem is the other checkboxlist gets uncheck it should be for Checkboxlist # 1-4 only. Is there any DOM : Get Element by that focus only in Checkboxlist # 1-4? Thank you very much.

Comment: @GlydelGorospe you can chain the getElements commands. So, have one that gets one of the tables (Checkboxlist #1), and walks that particular table looking for checkboxes (which is your function) and then do that for each of the  checkboxlists.